# cant get specific response in python POST

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

when i am trying to get a response on python using the requests library, it has no angle brackets and i cant do:

```
chatResponse = -requests.post method-

chatMessage = chatResponse.json()["gotMessage"]
```

when i do this, it doesnt give me the message that was sent by the other user ("Hi")

picture is below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qk2O5.png

if i need to post more code, let me know

Comment: someone pls help

Comment: The output as shown in picture is not a json object (in the form of dictionary). Maybe if you  do `chatResponse.json()[3][1]` then you may get desired output.

Comment: @user_3pij thank you so much dude! it works perfectly!